# PHP find duplicate files by comparing hash, and delete any duplicate files

Tags: php, arrays, hash, duplicates

I'm looping through files in a directory and saving name and hash in array like so:

```
$localfileslist = [];
$localfiles = glob($_GET['name'].'/*');
foreach($localfiles as $localfile){
    if(is_file($localfile)){
        $localfilehash= hash_file('sha256', $localfile);
         array_push($localfileslist,$localfile, $localfilehash);
    }
    }
    $uniques= array_unique($localfileslist);
    $dupes=array_diff_assoc($localfileslist,$aunique);
print_r($result);
```

Now, I'm stumped on how to proceed and finding dupes and deleting them; any help is appreciated

Comment: `$localfiles = glob($_GET['name'].'/*');`is a bad security risk. No sanitizing and everybody could put in what he wants.

Comment: What is in `$aunique`?

Answer (score 0):

Basically I first store each hash and name together. Then I group that array on the hash, pushing all same hashed names to each group. Finally we can filter that grouped array only having the items with more than 1 names.

```php
$localfileslist = [];
$localfiles = glob(DEFINE_PATH . '/*');
foreach ($localfiles as $localfile) {
    if (is_file($localfile)) {
        $localfilehash = hash_file('sha256', $localfile);
        array_push($localfileslist, ['name' => $localfile, 'hash' => $localfilehash]);
    }
}

$grouped = array_reduce($localfileslist, function ($agg, $item) {
    if (!isset($agg[$item['hash']])) {
        $agg[$item['hash']] = [];
    }
    $agg[$item['hash']][] = $item["name"];
    return $agg;
}, []);

$duplicates = array_filter($grouped, function ($item) {
    return count($item) > 1;
});

print_r($duplicates);
```